# jquery. if a link contains 'text' in the href. hide the link

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

a have an asp repeater that is repeating a links on a page with different urls. I want to hide any links (using jquery) that contain the word 'text' in their href. How can i do this?

```
if($(".fsproductsStcokistButton:contains('text')"))
{
    $(this).css("display", "none");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just chain it, like this:

```
$(".fsproductsStcokistButton:contains('text')").hide();
```

[`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) is a shortcut for the `display: none;`, and the selector itself will only return the elements that contain that text, so you're all set.  For an attribute check, like `href`, use an [attribute-contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/), like this:

```
$(".fsproductsStcokistButton[href*='text']").hide();
```

Comment: ive tried this but its not making the link disappear. i was wondering if contains would work because ive only used it for elements that encapsulate text like divs or labels whereas with a link i want to look at the href parameter.

Comment: @phil - In that case you need something like `".fsproductsStcokistButton[href*='text']"`.

Comment: thats nick. didnt realise you could call on parameters that way!